# How would I rewrite this to use a lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

How could I rewrite the following to use a lambda instead of the inner function:

```
List<ExtraService> extraServices = product.getServices().getExtraService().stream()
            .map(new Function<com.novasol.bookingflow.api.entities.products.ExtraService, ExtraService>() {

                @Override
                public ExtraService apply(com.novasol.bookingflow.api.entities.products.ExtraService es) {
                    ExtraService extraService = new ExtraService();
                    extraService.setServiceId(es.getServiceID());
                    extraService.setPriceUnitCode(es.getPriceUnitCode().intValue());
                    extraService.setServiceGroup(es.getServiceGroup().intValue());
                    extraService.setMaxUnits(es.getMaxUnits().intValue());

                    return extraService;
                }

            }).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Another idea could be to have a copy constructor and then `.map(ExtraService::new)`

Comment: @AlexisC. Interesting point - like the cleanliness of this and will do some experimentation here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
List<ExtraService> extraServices = product.getServices().getExtraService().stream()
        .map( es -> {
                ExtraService extraService = new ExtraService();
                extraService.setServiceId(es.getServiceID());
                extraService.setPriceUnitCode(es.getPriceUnitCode().intValue());
                extraService.setServiceGroup(es.getServiceGroup().intValue());
                extraService.setMaxUnits(es.getMaxUnits().intValue());

                return extraService;
            }

        ).collect(toList());
```

?

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options.

First - declare a function in your method

```
Function<com.novasol.bookingflow.api.entities.products.ExtraService, ExtraService> toService = es -> {
        ExtraService extraService = new ExtraService();
        extraService.setServiceId(es.getServiceId());
        extraService.setPriceUnitCode(es.getPriceUnitCode().intValue());
        extraService.setServiceGroup(es.getServiceGroup().intValue());
        extraService.setMaxUnits(es.getMaxUnits().intValue());
        return extraService;
    };

    List<ExtraService> extraServices = product.getServices().getExtraService()
            .stream()
            .map(toService)
            .collect(toList());
```

Second - declare a new method that does do the conversion and use a method reference to it

```
 private ExtraService toService(com.novasol.bookingflow.api.entities.products.ExtraService es) {
        ExtraService extraService = new ExtraService();
        extraService.setServiceId(es.getServiceId());
        extraService.setPriceUnitCode(es.getPriceUnitCode().intValue());
        extraService.setServiceGroup(es.getServiceGroup().intValue());
        extraService.setMaxUnits(es.getMaxUnits().intValue());
        return extraService;
}

public void yourCurrentMethod() {
        List<ExtraService> extraServices = product.getServices().getExtraService()
            .stream()
            .map(this::toService)
            .collect(toList());
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer :-)